# Linux signal handler established with SIGINFO doesn't result in signals being queued reliablly

Tags: c, linux, signals

It is my program

```
void handler (int signo, siginfo_t * info, void *) {
    printf("signo = %d\n", signo);
}

int main() {
    struct sigaction act;
    act.sa_flags = 0;
    act.sa_flags |= SA_RESTART;
    act.sa_flags |= SA_SIGINFO;
    act.sa_sigaction = handler;
    sigaction(SIGQUIT, &act, NULL);

    // block quit signal
    sigset_t newmask;
    sigaddset(&newmask, SIGQUIT);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &newmask, NULL);

    printf("send quit signals many times to me\n");
    sleep(20);

    // pending?
    sigset_t pending_set;
    sigpending(&pending_set);
    if(sigismember(&pending_set, SIGQUIT)) {
        printf("pending\n");
    } else {
        printf("not pending\n");
    }

    // unblock quit signal
    sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &newmask, NULL);
    while(1);
}
```

This is what I do while sleeping

```
[markity@mycom ~]$ kill -QUIT 3676
[markity@mycom ~]$ kill -QUIT 3676
[markity@mycom ~]$ kill -QUIT 3676
[markity@mycom ~]$ kill -QUIT 3676
[markity@mycom ~]$ kill -QUIT 3676
[markity@mycom ~]$ kill -QUIT 3676
[markity@mycom ~]$ kill -QUIT 3676
[markity@mycom ~]$
```

After a long time, the program output this

```
[markity@mycom theory]$ ./main
send quit signals many times to me
pending
signo = 3
```

It shows that while blocking, only one signal is reserved and the others are discarded. But I learned from `APUE` that a signal established with `SIGINFO` will make reliable queue. Do I misunderstand this?

This is the original text from `APUE`

[image: text from APUE]

[Edit]

this is my expected output

```
send quit signals many times to me
pending
signo = 3
signo = 3
signo = 3
signo = 3
signo = 3
signo = 3
signo = 3
```

Comment: Real-time signals (numbers between SIGRTMIN and SIGRTMAX) are queued reliably.  Other signals (smaller numbers) are not necessarily queued reliably — you may only get one call to the signal handler even if you send multiple signals.  The quoted manual supports the theory that real-time signals are key to your problem.